# Prove that the limit of the ratio is 0

Tags: calculus, limits, contest-math, normal-distribution

Given $y>x>0$,  and $x$, $y \sim N(0,1)$.  Show

$$\lim_{x \to \infty, y \to x} \frac{\frac{x+y}{2}-\frac{2}{\frac{1}{x}+\frac{1}{y}}}{\frac{x+y}{2}-\frac{\phi(x)-\phi(y)}{\Phi(y)-\Phi(x)}}=0$$

where $\phi$ is the density, and $\Phi$ is the distribution of the standard normal.

I have tried that as $y \to x$, $$\frac{\phi(x)-\phi(y)}{\Phi(y)-\Phi(x)} \to \frac{\phi'(x)}{-\Phi'(x)}=\frac{\phi(x)(-x)}{-\phi(x)}=x$$, and don't know how to proceed. Any idea would be helpful!

Comment: It seems difficult to compute this limit. Have you tried Taylor series?

Comment: Hi Jack, thanks for your comment! I tried to expand the density and distribution using Taylor, but $x$ and $y$ go to $\infty$, not $0$, the higher-order terms cannot be thrown away, right?

Comment: Glad to see your feedback. There are ways to transform the situation. I will write an answer soon.

Comment: Thanks for writing back! I am looking forward to your answer and really appreciate your help!

Comment: While it is not hard to prove $\lim_{x\to\infty}\lim_{y\to x}\text{that  fraction}=0$, I have not convinced myself the original limit is $0$ yet.

Comment: Hi Jack, happy to see you writing back and still remember the question! The original limit is my conjecture from some simulation results (the code can be seen in the other question posted by me). Maybe the limit condition is too strong or too weak than necessary. Could you kindly explain what the proof looks like? Thank you in advance!